# Query in MongoDB nested field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named **articles**. This collection have these documents:

```
{
    "title": "Blandit lacinia erat",
    "author": "Delcine",
    "volumeNumber": ["2021", "June"]
}

{
    "title": "At nunc commodo placerat",
    "author": "Robby",
    "volumeNumber": ["2021", "June"]
}

{
    "title": "ipsum aliquam non",
    "author": "Cheri",
    "volumeNumber": ["2021", "July"]
}

{
    "title": "cras non velit nec",
    "author": "Frederich",
    "volumeNumber": ["2021", "July"]
}
```

I want this output:

```
{
    "title": "Blandit lacinia erat",
    "author": "Delcine",
    "volumeNumber": ["2021", "June"]
}

{
    "title": "At nunc commodo placerat",
    "author": "Robby",
    "volumeNumber": ["2021", "June"]
}
```

So I wrote this query:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
{"$match": {"volumeNumber": ["2021", "June"]}},
{"$project": {"_id": 0, "title": 1, "author": 1, "volumeNumber": 1}}
])
```

But it returns nothing. How can I get my desired output?

Comment: But your query returns the result as the expected result. [Sample Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tt6HaKzkmNC)

Comment: As @YongShun has pointed out, your query should be fine. One of the common mistakes that causing empty return is using incorrect database/collection. Please check whether you are querying on the correct database/collection.

Answer (score 0):

The match statement should be something like:

```
"$match": {"$and" : [ {"volumeNumber":"2021"},{"volumeNumber":"June"} ] }
```